# Get persons full name from their First and Surname

Tags: c#, .net

My `Person` class has two properties; name and surname, and a function that returns the first name and the surname together.

Is there anything that can be done better? Anything that is done poorly?

```
public class Person
{
    private string Firstname { get; set; }
    private string Surname { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstname, string surname)
    {
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Surname = surname;

    }
    public string GetFullName()
    {
        string fullname = String.Format("Firstname is: {0}, Surname is {1}", Firstname, Surname);
        return fullname;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider making `Firstname` and `Surname` public with a private setter.

Comment: I don't think exposing a "Full Name", whether by method or property, is useful. I'd much rather have both the first name and surname exposed, and I as a client could then use and format that information as I see fit. Maybe I want to display it as `Surname, Forename` rather than `Forename Surname`, or I want to perform sorting on either property, etc.

Answer (score 9):

**Naming**

Whenever you have a simple method that starts with `Get`, it's an indication that should should consider making it a property (in this case a read only one).

**Unnecessary variable**
The `fullname` variable is unnecessary, you might was well return simply the result of the `String.Format`.

**Alternate for higher .Net versions**

Depending on your .Net version, you might also want to use string interpolation instead.  If you combine these three things then your `GetFullName` becomes:

```
public string FullName { 
                  get { return $"Firstname is: {Firstname}, Surname is {Surname}"; } 
              }
```

As an aside, usually you would simply expect the combined full name, rather than it being explicitly stated which is which, so you would have:

```
get { return $"{Firstname} {Surname}"; }
```

or using the [expression bodied auto property](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/12/17/c-6-feature-review-expression-bodied-function-members/) suggested by @Risky Martin you would end up with simply this:

```
public string FullName => $"{Firstname} {Surname}";
```

**Parameter Validation**

It may seem trivial for such a small class, but depending on the use case you should consider if you need to add validation to your constructor.  Is it really valid to construct a `Person` with a `null` or empty string for example?  As has been said by @Rick Davin, do you really want/need the setter for `FirstName` and `Surname` to be public, does it make sense for a `Person` object to change its name?  If it does make sense, then again, you should consider if rather than using the auto property you should be performing validation in your `set` methods.

Comment: C# 6.0 has syntax for even terser property getters:  `public string FullName => $"{Firstname} {Surname}";`

Comment: @RiskyMartin I hadn't noticed that before, it's quite nice for simple methods like this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstname, string surname)
    {
        FullName = $"Firstname is: {firstname}, Surname is {surname}";
    }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
}
```

Seeing you class I found you don't need to generate FullName each time calling a method and you don't need any private properties also. Keep it simple.

Comment: `private set` does not convey immutability the way `readonly` does. There is no need for `FullName` to be modified independently from the other properties; a get-only property with a backing field is semantically much closer to the intent. C# 6 introduced immutable get-only properties; this answer could be improved with a C# 6 example IMO.